# Finding fundamental particles of sound In ASR systems?

Tags: phonemes, speech-recognition

Q1. Can we divide phonemes which are specific to a language into some more fundamental entities same across all languages ?

Q2. Will this help us in achieving language independent acoustic modelling ?

Q3. What are the challenges, If any in above technique ?

Q4. Is there any project using this stuff currently ?

Answer (score 1):

> Can we divide phonemes which are specific to a language into some more fundamental entities same across all languages ?

There is the spectrogram (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram), maybe that is more fundamental than you wanted.  The raw datasets are just .wav or .mp3 files.

None of that is specific to language.  The language-specific part is really the transcription and language model on the output side.

> Will this help us in achieving language independent acoustic modelling?

Yes, end-to-end approaches (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition#End-to-end_automatic_speech_recognition) make it easier to train and launch models into more languages, and also to train models for macro-languages like Chinese or Arabic.

> What are the challenges, if any, in above technique?

Where should we begin?  Data, data, data, machines, fundamental challenges of human language like ambiguity and mixed language...

> Is there any project using this stuff currently?

Most of them now use deep learning, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition#Deep_feedforward_and_recurrent_neural_networks), for example https://research.mozilla.org/machine-learning/ (https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech).

There are experiments with universal models and the fundamentals are in favour of it but to my limited knowledge most of the models in production today are still specific to a language.  UI or spoken language identification system routes a live input to the hopefully right model.